# Graphviz as a library: Create multiple graphs results in error

Tags: c, graphviz

I'm creating a small C-program that needs to create multiple graphs. The dot for these graphs are in a string, so I'm using `agmemread` instead of `agread` (I want to avoid creating temporary files). However, it seems to break when calling `agmemread` more than once.

The following example outputs "error2", so it fails the second time when calling `agmemread`:

```
#include <gvc.h>

int main() {
  Agraph_t *g1 = agmemread("graph testgraph {\n\n}");

  if (!g1) {
    printf("error1\n");
    return 1;
  }

  agclose(g1);

  Agraph_t *g2 = agmemread("graph testgraph {\n\n}");

  if (!g2) {
    printf("error2\n");
    return 1;
  }

  agclose(g2);
  return 0;
}
```

In a real life example, there would be some more code between these sections of course.

Do I need to free or close anything before calling agmemread the second time? Or is it a Bug of graphviz? I'm using `graphviz: stable 2.30.1, devel 2.31.20130523.0446` on Mac OS X.

The same example with `agread` instead works like a charm.

Comment: Libraries like this usually have some kind of "char *get_error()" function that returns a string describing the last error encountered. I haven't studied this library too carefully yet, but is there anything of the sort in the header files (case-insensitive search for "error")? Providing a NULL handle as the ONLY feedback in a failure case is unusual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in agmemread(). The fix should appear in packages starting 18 June 2013. Thanks for reporting it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding "\n" after the closing "}" of each graph solves the issue.    I'm still investigating why this is required, syntactically.